# yii framework yahoo php hosting

Tags: php, yii, hosting

I would like to know whether yahoo php hosting supports yii framework by default , or we need to configure at our own risks. I contacted yahoo technical support team , they gave me an url http://ysbdemowebsite.in/phpinfo

In that above url I couldn't find any yii info. Currently I am having php application built on the top of yii framework and also i am looking for best php hosting with yii support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yii does not require anything special. Perhaps the only more-or-less no so standard requirement would be PDO. Yii comes with a requirments script, which you can run in order to know if your server is ready to work with yii.

Answer (score 1):

YII is just a framework and I have never came across to know that there is any special requirement for YII Framework code hosting. It runs on all the hosting environments ... You just need to check if your hosting provider has the compatible PHP & mySQL database support?

Once you develop your code, just Upload whole Webroot /App/ directory inside "public_html" folder.

I am hosting one of my website developed with YII framework at AccuWebHosting.Com.

Answer (score 0):

Well! There are dedicated VPS providers like DigitalOcean, Vultr, AWS which provides Yii hosting infact! for all versions of Yii. You just need to set up a PHP Lamp stack and then deploy your application on it. Also if you are not a sysadmin and don't want to go in Linux command system then you can use any managed hosting provider like Cloudways, Siteground, Platform.sh etc.